# Formulario JS enviar para um PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Atualmente eu desenvolvi um formulario em HTML e validei o mesmo com JS, agora estou querendo enviar essas dados para um banco MYSQL, porem estou usando no ACTION do formulario o endereço de uma pagina em PHP, que contem toda a estrutura para inserir no banco.

Agora minha duvida e como integrar essas linguagens e se esta correto o que eu fiz ?

Comment: Você quer enviar os dados da maneira tradicional (que recarrega a página) ou por ajax?

Comment: Eu quero enviar no metodo tradicional, porem a minha pagina PHP tem um paragrafo, apenas para eu saber se foi enviado para o banco ou não, nem chego a usar ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está. Através do atributo `action` de um formulário você define qual será a URL para qual serão enviados os dados do formulário. Isto é, quando o formulário for submetido, o navegador se encarrega de gerar outra requisição HTTP para a URL em `action`, utilizando o método definido em `method`; se `method="GET"`, uma requisição GET será efetuada e, se `method="POST"`, uma requisição POST será feita. Como o objetivo é enviar informações à um recurso no servidor, faz mais sentido utilizar o método POST.

```
<form action="cadastrar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Para o exemplo acima, ao pressionar o botão *Cadastrar*, o formulário será submetido, gerando, assim, uma requisição POST à `cadastrar.php`, executando-o. No código PHP, o valor digitado no campo estará disponível na superglobal `$_POST`:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Se está fazendo algo semelhante a isso, sim, está fazendo certo.

Comment: estou utilizando exatamente esse conceito, chamando no action a minha pagina php que ira enviar os dados para o banco, porem quando clico no botão ENVIAR nada acontece na pagina, eu cheguei a verificar no modo console do navegador o NETWORK e não chega a fazer a requisição para o PHP.

Comment: @Diogodgo então seu código JS que efetua a validação deve estar bloqueando a submissão do formulário.

Comment: Existe alguma condição no JS, que poderia anular esse submit, exemplo básico você teria ?

Comment: @Diogodgo, sim, um `return false`, um `event.preventDefault()`, etc. Seria melhor você editar a pergunta e inserir o código que possui até o momento.

Comment: Eu tenho na minha pagina esse event.preventDefault(), vou trabalhar numa forma de não utilizar ele. Obrigado pela ajuda, se eu encontrar dificuldade nesse aspecto, irei abrir uma outra pergunta, a minha duvida mesmo era se eu estava utilizando os conceitos corretos.